# Difference between @component and @scope for prototype bean in spring

Tags: spring

I am using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean to locate a prototype bean.

1. Whenever, I tried to access a prototype bean by defining bean with

   ```
   @Component(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   ```

then I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'square' available.
```

2. But, when I define the bean using

   ```
   @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   ```

then I am not getting error. In this case, I am getting two separate beans.

Please help me understand why is it so?

Comment: Presumably, you are attempting to inject a bean named `square` (from the error stack trace). `@Component(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` is the same as `@Component(value = "prototype")`, which means that the annotated class is a Spring-managed bean and its logical name is `prototype`. Since `prototype != square`, Spring rightly fails to find a component named `square` with this configuration. The point to remember is that the value passed to `@Component` represents the logical name of the Spring-managed bean, not its lifecycle scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

creates a component with name "prototype"

```
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

is a scope of component with name from class so you try to find a component named 'square' but you have component named 'prototype'.